# Is it possible to set the sameSite policy to none for cookies in amplify configuration?

Tags: cookies, iframe, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to set the sameSite policy of my amplify authentication's cookies at none.

I need to set this policy because I have to access those cookies in an iframe embedded in a different domain website.

My iframe is considered as third party because the top level site has a diferent domain from the url in the iframe. The CognitoIdentityServiceProvider cookie are not send because of the cross origin context so and the user logged in in the site is not logged in the iframe.

I tried to change the cookies sameSite policy following amplify docs :
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/client-configuration/configuring-amplify-categories/q/platform/js/#general-configuration

```
 // (optional) - Configuration for cookie storage
    // Note: if the secure flag is set to true, then the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol
    cookieStorage: {
      // - Cookie domain (only required if cookieStorage is provided)
      domain: '.yourdomain.com',
      // (optional) - Cookie path
      path: '/',
      // (optional) - Cookie expiration in days
      expires: 365,
      // (optional) - See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
      sameSite: 'strict' | 'lax',
      // (optional) - Cookie secure flag
      // Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol (https).
      secure: true
    },
```

The sameSite='none' seems not to work in amplify configuration is there any way to share Cognito auth cookies in cross origin context ?

Comment: Welcome. 'seems not to work in amplify configuration' isn't enough information to debug the issue, can you show us your exact configuration and how you're trying to do this?

Comment: `Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
      ...,
      cookieStorage: {
        domain: ".mydomain.com",
        path: "/",
        sameSite: "none",
        expires: 365,
        secure: true
      }
    },
    Storage: {
      ...
    }
  }); ` @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Can you please add it, in a formatted manner, to the question? And you still haven't clarified what *seems not to work in amplify configuration* means. Any console or network errors? `sameSite` being `none` is supported in Amplify. And are you running this on `localhost`?